# how to set http request header before cross domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, cross-domain

now i need to use ajax to get a restful api, but the rest api's readme says:

The response format is set by the "Accept" header.
For example, to query all resources on eg and get the response in json the following curl command could be used 
curl '192.168.2.21:4414/apiv1/eg/?depth=2' -H 'Accept: application/json'

so i have to 
1)cross domain to get the rest api
2)set the "accept" of http request header {application/json}

at begin i try to use jsonp, but it can not do the second one.so which way can i do both?
Thank you